# Rhino ETL C# DelimitedRecord

Tags: rhino-etl

I would like to know if are there a way to ignore the DelimitedRecord if it found in my file a string like "70,000 - 99,999"

File Sample:

1, "70,000 - 99,999"
6, "20,000 - 99,999"
8, "50,000 - 99,999"

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string id;
    public string Size;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

I need to use [FieldQuoted()] annotation on that field.